# How to detect that animation has ended on UITableView beginUpdates/endUpdates?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am inserting/deleting table cell using `insertRowsAtIndexPaths/deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` wrapped in `beginUpdates/endUpdates`. I am also using `beginUpdates/endUpdates` when adjusting rowHeight. All these operations are animated by default.

How can I detect that animation has ended when using `beginUpdates/endUpdates`?

Comment: FYI: This applies to `-scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` as well.

Answer (score 298, accepted):

What about this?

```
[CATransaction begin];

[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    // animation has finished
}];

[tableView beginUpdates];
// do some work
[tableView endUpdates];

[CATransaction commit];
```

This works because the tableView animations use `CALayer` animations internally. That is, they add the animations to any open `CATransaction`. If no open `CATransaction` exists (the normal case), then one is implicitly began, which is ended at the end of the current runloop. But if you begin one yourself, like is done here, then it will use that one.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Completion block is called while the animation is still running.

Comment: @MrVincenzo Did you set the `completionBlock` before `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` like in the snippet?

Comment: Yes. I am implementing the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol. `[CATransaction begin]` is called in `controllerWillChangeContent` just before `[tableView beginUpdates]`. Same thing in `controllerDidChangeContent`. `[CATransaction commit]` is called before `[tableView endUpdates]`.

Comment: `[CATransaction commit]` should be called after not before `[tableView endUpdates]`.

Comment: My mistake. It is called after as you suggested. I already reverted this aforementioned code. I will give it another try and update. Thanks.

Comment: Rudolf Adamkovic, would you mind explain how this works, maybe update in your answer?

Comment: Completion block is never called if a cell contains a view with animations, ie UIActivityIndicatorView.

Comment: Thanks! Works nice with `-reloadData` too so I can get correct content size right after table end reloading and set content align to bottom of screen

Comment: After all this time I never knew this. Pure Gold !! Nothing worse then seeing a nice animation getting killed with the necessary evil of tableView.reloadData().

Comment: Works for me only if I set all CATransaction actions after endUpdates

Comment: should probably set "[myUITableView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]" before the animation begins and undo this on completion.

Answer (score 34):

Swift Version

---

```
CATransaction.begin()

CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
    do.something()
})

tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()

CATransaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're targeting iOS 11 and above, you should use `UITableView.performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)` instead:

```swift
tableView.performBatchUpdates({
    // delete some cells
    // insert some cells
}, completion: { finished in
    // animation complete
})
```

Answer (score 5):

A possible solution could be to inherit from the UITableView on which you call `endUpdates` and overwrite its `setContentSizeMethod`, since UITableView adjusts its content size to match the added or removed rows. This approach should also work for `reloadData`.

To ensure that a notification is sent only after `endUpdates` is called, one could also overwrite `endUpdates` and set a flag there.

```
// somewhere in header
@private BOOL endUpdatesWasCalled_;

-------------------

// in implementation file

- (void)endUpdates {
    [super endUpdates];
    endUpdatesWasCalled_ = YES;
}

- (void)setContentSize:(CGSize)contentSize {
    [super setContentSize:contentSize];

    if (endUpdatesWasCalled_) {
        [self notifyEndUpdatesFinished];
        endUpdatesWasCalled_ = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can enclose your operation(s) in UIView animation block like so:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView performOperation:(void(^)())operation completion:(void(^)(BOOL finished))completion
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0 animations:^{

        [tableView beginUpdates];
        if (operation)
            operation();
        [tableView endUpdates];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        if (completion)
            completion(finished);
    }];
}
```

Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/12905114/634940.

Comment: This code did not work for me. The completion block was called after `endUpdates`, but before the animations had completed.

Comment: This doesn't work. The tableview animation stopped working, when applying this sample.

Comment: Try making the duration longer (like 0.3 sec) - it should work (it worked for me)

Answer (score 1):

Haven't found a good solution yet (short of subclassing UITableView). I've decided to use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` for now. Not ideal, but gets the job done.

**UPDATE**: It looks like I can use `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:` for this purpose (this is specific to my implementation, see comment).

Comment: `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` is only called in response to `setContentOffset` and `scrollRectToVisible`

Comment: @samvermette Well, in my case, when beginUpdates/endUpdates are called, the UITableView always animate-scroll. But this is specific to my implementation, so I agree it's not the best answer but it works for me.

Comment: Seems it is possible to enclose updates into an UIView animation block. See my answer bellow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14305039/634940.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"tableView willDisplay Cell");
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:((indexPath.row % 2) ? 0.25 : 0) alpha:0.70];
}
```

But this will also get called when a cell that is already in the table moves from off the screen to on the screen so it may not be exactly what you are looking for.  I just looked through all the `UITableView` and `UIScrollView` delegate methods and there doesnt appear to be anything to handle just after a cell is inserted animation.

---

Why not just call the method you want to be called when the animation ends after the `endUpdates`?

```
- (void)setDownloadedImage:(NSMutableDictionary *)d {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath *)[d objectForKey:@"IndexPath"];
    [indexPathDelayed addObject:indexPath];
    if (!([table isDragging] || [table isDecelerating])) {
        [table beginUpdates];
        [table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathDelayed withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [table endUpdates];
        // --> Call Method Here <--
        loadingView.hidden = YES;
        [indexPathDelayed removeAllObjects];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, chown. Don't think `willDisplayCell` will work. I need it to happen after the animation because I need to make a visual update only after everything settles.

Comment: np @pixelfreak, if I think of any other way to do this I'll let ya know.