# Call a method after [self.tableView endUpdates] ended

Tags: iphone, uitableview, animation, ios5

I want to add my sliderButton after the animation has ended but this doesn't work, it adds the button while the deletion of the section is being animated.

```
    [coursesTable beginUpdates];
    [coursesTable deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [coursesTable endUpdates];
    [self.view addSubview:sliderButton];
```

Is there a possibility I can call a method that does that for me when the animation ended?

Comment: add sliderButton with some animation so that after animation of deletion of the section is complete your button is added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the answer here:

[How to detect that animation has ended on UITableView beginUpdates/endUpdates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623771/how-to-detect-that-animation-has-ended-on-uitableview-beginupdates-endupdates)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 7):

I believe that wrapping your table update in `animateWithDuration` would work:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.0 animations:^{
    [coursesTable beginUpdates];
    …
    [coursesTable endUpdates];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // Code to run when table updates are complete.
}];
```

Other methods that I found suggested here on Stack Overflow did not work for me.

I used this technique at one time and tested it enough to verify that the completion block was called after I called the table's endUpdates method, but rewrote my code so I didn't need it any more before I had completely verified that the animation was actually finished.

Comment: Using this method will skip the animating part of the animation and simply complete it instantly, even if you put in a longer duration like 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

I have also not found the solution of this.I have to use   performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: for getting my work done.

Answer (score 0):

```
[coursesTable deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

after this the `tableview` again asks data from its **datasource**... so all the datasource methods including `cellforRow` is again called..

i suggest keeping a BOOL is Deleting.

so now do this

```
    [coursesTable beginUpdates];
        [coursesTable deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [coursesTable endUpdates];
Deleting = YES;
```

**in cellForRow method**

```
{
if (index path.row == lastrow ) // last rowcell is reached
if(Deleting)
{
//tableView has reloaded.
    [self.view addSubview:sliderButton];
    Deleting = NO;;


}
}
```