# UISegmentedControl insert animation completion handler

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

UISegmentedControl has a method:

```
- (void)insertSegmentWithTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSUInteger)segment animated:(BOOL)animated
```

If I set the animated to true, is there a way for me to find out when the animation is completed(i.e. completion handler, animation delegate, duration)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time back I also faced this kind to problem to check animation complete of `UITableView`, I have found one very useful post - [Animation End Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623771/how-to-detect-that-animation-has-ended-on-uitableview-beginupdates-endupdates)

You can also use this approach for your use, Before posting this answer I have checked this on segment control and it is working well. You might use like -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil];

    self.segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
    self.segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(10, 100, 250, 50);
    self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    [self.view addSubview:self.segmentedControl];
}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"Animation finished");
    }];

    [self.segmentedControl insertSegmentWithTitle:@"Four" atIndex:3 animated:YES];
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

This works as the default animations use `CALayer` animations and here we define one implicit `CATransaction`.