# UITableView row/cell animation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation, reload

I have a UITableView, for which I am reloading each row with new data by using:

```
for currentIndex in (feeds.count-1).stride(through: 0, by: -1) {
    self.feedList[currentIndex] = feeds[currentIndex]

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()

        self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: currentIndex, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Middle)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

This makes all the rows animate together at once. What I want is for each row to animate one after the other. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried to use CATransaction and animate only one row at a time, and call the animation for the next row in CATransaction's completion block?

Answer (score 3):

The commentor is correct about `CATransaction`.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623771/how-to-detect-that-animation-has-ended-on-uitableview-beginupdates-endupdates)'s an example of how to combine what you have with `CATransaction` to get the proper animation sequence.  Save the stride that you want to animate, and iterate one more element through until you've animated them all.