# Inserting row after another row deletion animation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation

I'm trying to insert a row after another row deletion animation is completed. I've been trying doing the following:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
CATransaction.begin()

CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Right)
}

tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Left)

CATransaction.commit()
tableView.endUpdates
```

This gave me the usual assertion failure when the count of rows is not the same as it's been expecting.

Then I've tried using an `UIView` animation with a completion block:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()

func animations() {
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Left)
}

func completion() {
    if count == self.payments.count && self.payments.isEmpty { insert() }
}

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { animations() }) { _ in completion() }

tableView.endUpdates()
```

Both attempts is giving me the same error. Is it possible or should I look into custom animation for inserting / deleting tableview rows?

---

**Edit:**

I managed to make it work by moving `tableView.endUpdates()` to the completion block. But the insertion animation still animates at the same time when the row is being deleted.

Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

if you know how much time does your animation takes to complete just add this function to wait for a given amount of time before executing some code:

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

Usage:

```
delay(seconds: 0.5) { 
    //code to be delayed "0.5 sec"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're putting code in wrong position

It should be like this:

```
CATransaction.begin()

CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
  // animation has finished
}

tableView.beginUpdates()
// do some work
tableView endUpdates()

CATransaction.commit()
```

Reference: [How to detect that animation has ended on UITableView beginUpdates/endUpdates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623771/how-to-detect-that-animation-has-ended-on-uitableview-beginupdates-endupdates)